# Basis of a subspace in $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $U$ is a subspace $ U= \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R} \mid x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0\} $
>   Find a Basis of $U$.

I know a basis of the whole $\mathbb{R}^4$ needs at least 4 independent vectors, since it's only a subspace, I don't know how many I need. Are 2 vectors, fullfilling the equation, sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one condition, which as a rule of thumb removes only one from the dimension.
Formally:
$U$ is the kernel of the surjective linear map $\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R$, $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$. Therefore $\dim U + \dim \mathbb R=\dim \mathbb R^4$. In other words: you need three independant vectors.

One vector $\in U$ of particularly simple kind is $(1,-1,0,0)$. Can you see a few others like that? Are there enough linearly independant among them?

Comment: Basis means not only independent vectors but they need to be perpendicular as well.

Comment: perpendicular = linearly independent?

Comment: (1,−1,0,0)
(0,0,1,1)
(0,1,1,0)

Comment: Good answer, grat :-)

Comment: @Peter Horvath Only in an inner product space can we give that, which $R^4$ has, but there is not a inner product given here. There is not a necessity for orthogonality/perpendicular in general.

Answer (score 1):

2 vectors aren't enough. It is a 3D-plane in a 4D space. Its basis need to have 3, 4-dimensional vectors.

3 vectors: (1,0,0,-1), (0,1,0,-1), (0,0,1,-1).

Comment: thanks, how do I know how many different vectors I need for subspaces?
Or for every subspace n-1?

Comment: @SuperNova For simple, independent equations in simple spaces with real cordinates, every equation lowers the dimension with one.

Answer (score 1):

$U=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb {R^4}|x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0\}$

$=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb {R^4}|x_4=-x_1-x_2-x_3\}$

$=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,-x_1-x_2-x_3)\in \mathbb {R^4}|x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb R\}$

$=\{x_1(1,0,0,0,-1)+x_2(0,1,0,-1)+x_3(0,0,1,-1)|x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb R\}$

$=span\{(1,0,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$

We also see that $\{(1,0,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$ is linearly independent since

$c_1(1,0,0,0,-1)+c_2(0,1,0,-1)+c_3(0,0,1,-1)=(0,0,0,0)$ (for some scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$)

$\Rightarrow (c_1,c_2,c_3,-c_1-c_2-c_3)=(0,0,0,0)$

$\Rightarrow c_1=0,c_2=0,c_3=0$

So $dimU=3$